Is there a generic way to use SetReturnsDefault in Moq
I have a data access interface looking roughly like this:
public interface IDataRepository
{
    DatabaseResult<Customer> GetAllCustomers();
    DatabaseResult<Report> GetAllReports();
    DatabaseResult<Order> GetAllOrders();
    [..] (there are many methods like this)
}

DatabaseResult is a public class that is used to attach some metadata to the returned information.
When I mock this interface I want every single method (I probably have > 100) to return an instance of DatabaseResult<WhatEverType>. Currently I need to call SetReturnsDefault for each type, e.g.
    var mockDb = new Mock<IDataRepository>();
    mockDb.SetReturnsDefault(new DatabaseResult<Customer>());
    mockDb.SetReturnsDefault(new DatabaseResult<Report>());
    mockDb.SetReturnsDefault(new DatabaseResult<Order>());

Is there a way to just tell Moq that when the return type of a method is DatabaseResult<SomeType> then always return a new instance DatabaseResult<SomeType>, regardless of what SomeType is?
Or maybe, even more generically, there is a way to tell Moq to always return a new instance if the return type is class/record/struct? And for common generic collection interfaces like IEnumerable<T>, IList<T>, IDictionary<T>, etc., just return a random .NET type that implements the interface?

Actually there is already general solution to your problem.
You need to install two packages: AutoFixture and AutoFixture.AutoMoq.
Classes included there allows for automatic mocking of interfaces.
Please see example unit tests presenting how it can be used to autmatically mock all interface's methods:
public class GenericType<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IInterface
{
    GenericType<int> GetInt();
    GenericType<string> GetString();
    GenericType<object> GetObject();
}

public class AutoFixtureTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        // Arrange
        var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
        var mock = fixture.Create<Mock<IInterface>>().Object;

        // Act & Assert
        Assert.NotNull(mock.GetInt());
        Assert.NotNull(mock.GetString());
        Assert.NotNull(mock.GetObject());
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        // Arrange
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        var mock = fixture.Create<Mock<IInterface>>().Object;

        // Act & Assert
        Assert.Null(mock.GetInt());
        Assert.Null(mock.GetString());
        Assert.Null(mock.GetObject());
    }
}


It sounds that what you want is this:
var mock = new Mock<IDataRepository> {
    DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock
};

Comments from the source code:
    /// <summary>
    /// Whenever the default value generated by <see cref="Empty"/> 
    /// is null, replaces this value with a mock (if the type 
    /// can be mocked). 
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// For sealed classes, a null value will be generated.
    /// </remarks>
    Mock,

Or alternatively, extension method for the specific use case of generic type definition (DatabaseResult<>):
public static void SetReturnDefaultGenericTypeDefinition(this Mock mock, Type mockedType, Type genericTypeDefinition) {
    if (!genericTypeDefinition.IsGenericTypeDefinition) {
        throw new ArgumentException("Not a generic type definition");
    }

    // parameterless constructor 
    if (genericTypeDefinition.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) == null) {
        throw new ArgumentException("Generic type doesn't have parameterless ctor");
    }

    var returnTypesMethods = mockedType
        .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Select(x => x.ReturnType)
        .Where(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericTypeDefinition)
        .ToList();

    MethodInfo setReturnDefault = typeof(Mock).GetMethod(nameof(mock.SetReturnsDefault));
    foreach (var returnType in returnTypesMethods) {
        MethodInfo genSetRetunrDefault = setReturnDefault.MakeGenericMethod(returnType);
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(returnType);
        genSetRetunrDefault.Invoke(mock, new object[] { instance });
    }
}

and use:
mock.SetReturnDefaultGenericTypeDefinition(typeof(IDataRepository), typeof(DatabaseResult<>));

